# WatchService causing memory leak in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, watchservice

I have a `WatchService` for monitoring a folder for new and modified files.

Problem: the app runs on a `tomcat` server, and when I shutdown the server, the following error message is logged (plus it takes a long time until the server shuts down):

```
01-Oct-2015 08:58:11.998 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [myapp] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Stack trace of thread:
sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus0(Native Method)
sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(Unknown Source)
sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService$Poller.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

01-Oct-2015 08:58:11.998 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [myapp] appears to have started a thread named [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.take(Unknown Source)
sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.take(Unknown Source)
```

How could I fix this? My watchservice is just as usual:

```
WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
Path path = Paths.get(folder);
path.register(watchService, events);

WatchKey key = null;
while (true) {
    try {
        key = watchService.take();
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
            //etc
        }

        key.reset();
    } catch (ClosedWatchServiceException e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you don't invoke `java.nio.file.WatchService.close()` anywhere in your code; `java.nio.file.WatchService` implements `java.io.Closeable`which means that you can easily make sure you get rid of any memory leaks related to improper usage of `java.nio.file.WatchService` by using a try-with-resources (available since Java 7) block like so:

```
try(WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {

    Path path = Paths.get(folder);
    path.register(watchService, events);

    WatchKey key = null;
    while (true) {
        try {
            key = watchService.take();
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                //etc
            }

            key.reset();

        } catch(InterruptedException | ClosedWatchServiceException e) { 
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();            
        }
    }
}
```

Also please have a look at the [WatchService java spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html), reading documentation usually helps a lot.

```
The close method may be invoked at any time to close the service causing any threads waiting to retrieve keys, to throw ClosedWatchServiceException.
```

Comment: I tried as suggested, but still having the same error. On shutdown of tomcat, the exception is logged from line `watchService.take()`. Somehow this line causes the memory leak. But why? Maybe I can register a shutdown hook for the tomcat server, and close the watcher explicit?

Comment: Have you tried using `java.nio.file.WatchService#poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)` instead of `watchService.take()`?

Comment: Are you using an java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService to run the code you've shared so far?